# Cypress click on an element above my targeted element, at the same position

Tags: cypress

I have a div that contains two element on top of each other :

- one is a svg bar chart, where each bar is a rect with a data-test-id
- the other one is an input range laying on top of the bar chart, offsetted so that the range length matches the chart width. It covers the whole graph so that receives any click event on the graph. Its opacity is set to 0.01

Here is what it looks like :

[image]

When I click on bar matched by a test-id in a cypress, I would like it to update the range value, as it works in a standard browser.

However it does not. If I try to cy.click on my rect, it does not work because it only tries to click on the rect.

I tried computing the x, y position to click on the range input but it does not work sadly :

```
 cy.get("[data-test-id='2021-07-28T05:56:00Z']")
  .as("targetBar")
  .then(() =>
    cy.get('[data-test-id="conversations-offset-cursor"]').as("cursor")
  )
  .then(() => {
    const targetOffset = this.targetBar.offset();
    const cursorOffset = this.cursor.offset();

    const top = targetOffset.top - cursorOffset.top;
    const left = targetOffset.left - cursorOffset.left;

    cy.get('[data-test-id="conversations-offset-cursor"]').click({
      x: top,
      y: left,
      force: true,
    });
    return cy.wait(10000);
  });
```

But while the click is registered, and the x y coordinates seem relevant, it's as if I didn't set any coordinate at all. Here is the coordinates passed to the .click:

```
 click 19.646743774414062 867.7333374023438
```

And here is the click log :

[image]

**EDIT : I had mixed x and y coordinates, it clicks at the right place now, but still not triggering the event of the slider**

Comment: Hi. Even if I don't have a clear explanation for it yet, and it might not help, but I've manged a similar use case by using `trigger('click')` instead of `click()`.

Comment: @AlexIzbas thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it does not help :/

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I'm having a similar issue right now